# networking - No NAT when connected via Ethernet

Tags: networking, osx, nat

I'm having an issue on my MacBook Air getting NAT to work when connected via USB-to-Ethernet-Adapter, when I'm connected via WiFi everything works like expected.

If I `ping` something external (like google.com) I get the following error message:

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.22.46): 56 data bytes
36 bytes from XXXXXXXXX.XXXX.t-ipconnect.de (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX): Communication prohibited by filter
```

`ping`-ing to anything on my LAN and via WiFi everything works.

Network: 192.168.2.1/24
DNS: 192.168.2.2

WiFi IP Address (via DHCP): 192.168.2.136/24
Ethernet IP Address (via DHCP): 192.168.2.132/24

This issue is only on my MacBook, other devices in the same LAN are not affected by this issue. So I assume this must be an issue on my MacBook.

Here's my `ifconfig` output (only the necessary):

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 48:d7:05:XX:XX:XX
    inet6 fe80::14a9:ca2d:64fe:65ff%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x5
    inet 192.168.2.136 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en2: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 9c:eb:e8:XX:XX:XX
    inet6 fe80::1842:81e:8cc8:4cca%en2 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xb
    inet 192.168.2.132 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active
```

I already tried to use a static IP address without any result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have identical subnets (192.168.2.*/24) on both adapters. This cannot work (at least not easily). Try for example disabling the WLAN when connected via LAN.

Comment: Disabling WiFi and only enabling Ethernet doesn't work too. But why should it be a problem if both NICs are connected to the same Network? There are good reasons to have multiple NICs on the same host.